# Send number to a API

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem sending a number to my API

This is my code to send to the API

```
      verified_perfil(clientObject: clientModel): Observable<any> {
      console.log(clientObject);
    const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('Myphone', clientObject.phone)
    return this._http.post(this.url + 'personas/perfil',
    body.toString(),
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .set('Authorization', this._authSvc.giveTokenActiveUser())
      }
    );
  }
```

But the error is that the Myphone is string and i am sending a number... but toString() dont work becouse the api want a number

Comment: You put a `console.log` statement, it would be helpful to see the output of that.

Comment: If you want to convert clientObject.phone to number the use parseInt(clientObject.phone) or simply clientObject.phone*1. If you want to convert clientObject.phone from number to string, then use '' + clientObject.phone. Hope this helps

Comment: alternative to debugging with console.log, you can write "debugger" in your code or set breakpoint on the browser to see what is going on

Comment: Can you show your api code?

Comment: @buchipper If i parse to an INT: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: @RodrigoA - The HttpParams object's set method accepts a string key and a string value ( https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#set ). That is the reason you are getting the error. To set it properly, you need to pass the phone number as a string (For this, you can do '' + clientObject.phone. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. You will send a clean json to the server.

```
clientObject.MyPhone = Number(clientObject.phone);


return this._http.post(this.url + 'personas/perfil',clientObject,
{
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  .set('Authorization', this._authSvc.giveTokenActiveUser())
  }
);
```

Comment: but the other fields ?

Comment: Put the full client object to the request. I'll edit the answer.